# How to get comma separeted list form wp_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, class, categories

It seems that i can't get to find workaround for this, maybe custom walker ?

Im building a plugin and i'm listing all the inputs from database on one of my plugin page.

In the database i have list of categories id's which i retrieve in list. Categories id's are comma separated so it looks like

```
2, 32, 198, 23
```

As i understood the best way to retrieve those categories is with

```
wp_list_categories
```

So if i take a field value from database and insert it in wp_list_categories i get this

```
wp_list_categories(array( 'include' => 2, 32, 198, 23 ));
```

Which is working code and with this i output specific categories which i want.

The problem is that this outputs a list of categories as ul and li elements with link to each category

And this is not what i want. I want to get output of categories but comma separated and i don't need to link to each category

So in the end i need to get output of this

```
Category 2 name, Category 32 name, Category 198 name, Category 23 name
```

What are the options to do this. I was searching and maybe custom Walker would work which replace ul and li elements with comma but i don't have a clue how to format a Walker class.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) instead of [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) which will return an array of categories that you can manipulate (you'll probably use [`implode($catsString,',')`](http://php.net/implode) to get your comma separated list)

Comment: Ill upvote this as it's right direction to the answer. i already tried various combinations but couldn't isolate names from an array. I finally got an answer on wp forums there is a function called wp_list_pluck which makes things works.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević, the first two google results for `wp_list_pluck` are pretty informative: [(1)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) and [(2)](http://www.viper007bond.com/2012/03/10/wp_list_pluck-is-an-awesome-wordpress-function/). But look like you'd need to `implode` anyway. Nice function indeed :)

Comment: Yes but without a pluck function (this sounds like pljuke(spitting something)) i couldn't make it, first use get_categories() to get my cats, than wp_list_pluck to isolate names and in end implode to make it comma separated. im posting a working function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got an answer. the solution is actually using get_categories instead of wp_list_categories. This is how i isolated only names of selected categories and comma separated them

```
        $getcats = get_categories(array(
                'include' => $item['post_category'], <-- This returns list of categories id's like: 3, 32, 13, 45, 4
                'hide_empty' => 0
            ));
    $getcats = wp_list_pluck($getcats,'name');
    $getcats = implode(', ',$getcats);
```